# Creating dynamic table based on nested JSON using AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have nested JSON like below.

```
{
  "Group": [
    {
      "Module1": [
        {
          "Col1": "Value1 0",
          "Col2": "Value2 0",
          "Col3": "Value3 0",
          "Col4": "Value4 0"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Value1 1",
          "Col2": "Value2 1",
          "Col3": "Value3 1",
          "Col4": "Value4 1"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Value1 2",
          "Col2": "Value2 2",
          "Col3": "Value3 2",
          "Col4": "Value4 2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Module2": [
        {
          "Col1": "Value1 0",
          "Col2": "Value2 0",
          "Col3": "Value3 0",
          "Col4": "Value4 0",
          "Col5": "Value5 0",
          "Col6": "Value6 0"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Value1 1",
          "Col2": "Value2 1",
          "Col3": "Value3 1",
          "Col4": "Value4 1",
          "Col5": "Value5 1",
          "Col6": "Value6 1"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Value1 2",
          "Col2": "Value2 2",
          "Col3": "Value3 2",
          "Col4": "Value4 2",
          "Col5": "Value5 2",
          "Col6": "Value6 2"
        },
        {
          "Col1": "Value1 3",
          "Col2": "Value2 3",
          "Col3": "Value3 3",
          "Col4": "Value4 3",
          "Col5": "Value5 3",
          "Col6": "Value6 3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I will be having two tabs `Module1` and `Module2`
When user selects `Module1` then `Module1` related data has to be utilised to create a table like shown below.

```
=============================================
|  Col1    |   Col2   |   Col3   |   Col4   |
=============================================
| Value1 0 | Value2 0 | Value3 0 | Value4 0 |
| Value1 1 | Value2 1 | Value3 1 | Value4 1 |
| Value1 2 | Value2 2 | Value3 2 | Value4 2 |
=============================================
```

Note that table columns are dynamic. There wont be same number of columns for all Modules and I won't be knowing what column name I will get as response.

Please help me creating a table. I tried using `ng-repeat` but I'm getting only last data when I select `Module1`

> "Col4": "Value4 2"

**Update :**

---

Check Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/K77lRZOS2RuF4X8orzTk?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Arulkumar for editing my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

```
<table class="table" ng-repeat="(moduleName, dataset) in myJson.group">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="(colName, colValue) in dataset[0]" ng-bind="colName"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="dataObj in dataset">
            <td ng-repeat="(colName, colValue) in dataObj" ng-bind="colValue"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This should be a shot in the right direction.

---

Having a large dataset with eg. ng-repeat is a big performance bottleneck due to all the $$watchers you create, I would advise using a grid plugin which does virtualization such as [uiGrid](http://ui-grid.info/).

Comment: For each tab record wont go beyond 20. And number of tabs also will not exceed more than 20. Can you suggest solution without using external plugin. My clients are little reluctant when i use plugins. Also please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong in that JSON,

Comment: I tried your above code and the result i'm getting is weird. I'm getting only last column Col4 and its corresponding rows.

Comment: @vinothvs your data can't start with a $, that's reserved for Angular, if you remove the $ it works